# www-data can't find the ruby gems on vagrant configured virtualbox

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to get a virtual server running using Vagrant and VirtualBox. For the VirtualBox I'm using `scotch/box` which got all the basic stuff for running a ubuntu server with some components (apache, mysql, php etc.) more on scotchbox can be found here.

Now I got the server up and running (running a Yii2 application) but as soon as the application starts I get an Yii error message `sh: 1: sass: not found` and because of that a SASS file couldn't be converted to CSS. So I went back to my server to check if sass was installed, it wasn't so I ran the command `gem install sass` and after that sass was installed. `gem list sass -i` returned true.

But still the problem stayed, sass couldn't be found. I went back to my console and of course apache is ran by user `www-data` and I logged in to ssh with the vagrant user. And this is were it gets a bit vague for me. In the environments variables of the apache service I added the paths to both ruby and the gems. But still the www-data user cannot find the sass command or the gem command or even the ruby command.

I also tried to change the owner of the apache service from www-data to the vagrant user that did kinda help but thats not the solution I want to accept. I want a solution that the apache service stays owned by the www-data user and not a root user like vagrant.

If more data needs to be added please let me know.

**Envvars file**

```
    envvars - default environment variables for apache2ctl

# this won't be correct after changing uid
unset HOME

# for supporting multiple apache2 instances
if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
    SUFFIX="-${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
else
    SUFFIX=
fi

# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
# temporary state file location. This might be changed to /run in Wheezy+1
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
# Only /var/log/apache2 is handled by /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX

## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale

export LANG

## The command to get the status for 'apache2ctl status'.
## Some packages providing 'www-browser' need '--dump' instead of '-dump'.
#export APACHE_LYNX='www-browser -dump'

## If you need a higher file descriptor limit, uncomment and adjust the
## following line (default is 8192):
#APACHE_ULIMIT_MAX_FILES='ulimit -n 65536'

## If you would like to pass arguments to the web server, add them below
## to the APACHE_ARGUMENTS environment.
#export APACHE_ARGUMENTS=''

## Enable the debug mode for maintainer scripts.
## This will produce a verbose output on package installations of web server modules and web application
## installations which interact with Apache
#export APACHE2_MAINTSCRIPT_DEBUG=1
export GEM_HOME=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
export GEM_PATH=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
export MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3
export IRBRC=/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/.irbrc
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: if you go back from start and do `su -l www-data gem install sass` does it help ?

Comment: I tried installing it by swithcing users but it returned the following message `-su: 0: Can't open gem` it looks like the user `www-data` doesn't have any knowledge of the commands that are available for the normal vagrant user

Comment: hum .. if you install with the root user then `sudo gem install sass`

Comment: It works for the root user but still the www-data can't find the gem command. Just like I said in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find out whether the PATH that apache uses is indeed modified by your adjustments of the envvars file. You could do this by simply putting running this php code: 
`var_dump(getenv("PATH"));
die;`

I've had the exact same problem. After a long time trying it turned out that `service apache2 stop` and `start` in vagrant is not working as expected. After setting the PATH variable in `/etc/apache2/envvars` try reloading apache by reloading vagrant instead: `vagrant reload`

Comment: I tried this and it does indeed return the values that are set in the envvars file. I added my envvars file to the question.

Comment: try running the newest Scotch Box with Ruby 2.2.2 and RBEnv and adding this to your envvars: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims/:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims/gem`